# Eclipse Plugin Project with JGit implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, jgit

I am creating an eclipse plugin with jgit implementation, thus I need a way to show the development history of a project. I guess I need to write the java code to add, commit and push to a repository from the eclipse plugin. How would I be able to do this? Searching the web has given limited help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are considering some nice new git visualization features. Perhaps adding them to [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/)  would be best. EGit is already a consumer of the JGit library, so there should be lots of example code to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) provides a number of ready to run snippets for many such tasks. And the sources of [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) will provide hints how things can be done in Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 0):

[EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) is providing this already